# How to Summarize a Logistic Regression from statsmodel

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I wrote the code bellow, but I'd like to make a summary from statsmodel, can someone help me please ?

Thank you.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = df[['age_over_65', 'female_perc', 'foreign_born_perc','bachelors_perc', 'household_income']]
y = df['winner']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
model = logmodel.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sci-Kit learn is focused on machine learning performance rather than statistical inference.

If you want to see summary results for a logit model you are better off using [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.logit.html)

Example code below.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
X = df[['age_over_65', 'female_perc', 'foreign_born_perc','bachelors_perc', 'household_income']]
y = df['winner']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
XVARS = ['age_over_65', 'female_perc', 'foreign_born_perc','bachelors_perc', 'household_income']
target = 'winner'
model = smf.logit(formula=f"{target} ~ {' + '.join(XVARS)}", data=df.loc[X_train.index])
logmodel = model.fit()
logmodel.summary2()

#to save in a text file.

with open('logit_results.txt'), 'w') as text_file:
    print(logmodel.summary2(), file=text_file)
```